# Is possible to use release-it from the develop branch?

Tags: git, release

I've inherited a website whose code is in git repository and which uses [release-it](https://github.com/release-it/release-it).

However, I'm having trouble on understanding what is the right approach to use that package to publish new releases.

I've seen that on develop, the version in the `package.json` is `1.8.0` while on master is `4.0.0`. The latter is the actually the tag currently used in the production server.

If I try to run `npm run release` from the develop branch I get a huge changelog, with commits already merged in the past in main\in a tag.

The message log shows

> Let's release myproject (1.8.0...2.0.0)

So I can understand this behavior.

However, if I try force the version with `npm run release -- --release-as 4.1.0` or try to increase on develop the version in the package.json file to `4.0.0`
I get the same message and behaviour.

Any idea why it is happening and how to solve it? I haven't finished the process, aka
confirmed the following various step, such as

> Commit (Release 5.0.0)? (Y/n)

Because I don't know what could happen and if I could revert easily.

Comment: Maybe you should do this manually for a while before trying what looks like a very automated and opinionated tool? That’s just my first impression (maybe I’m speaking out of line).

Comment: What branching strategy are you using and what is the relationship between `develop` and `master`? Why is `develop` so far behind `master` for the version of that file?